# ls -ltr in perl

Tags: perl, directory

I want to replicate ls -ltr unix command in perl script without using backticks, exec or system. Following script is working:

```
use strict;
my $dir="/abc/xyz/log";
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Can not open $dir $!";
my @latest = (sort {-M $b <=> -M $a} <$dir/*>);
my @latest2= grep { !/^\./ && -f "$_"} @latest;
closedir DIR;
```

Question: How can I combine the sort and grep in a single line so that I can do away with @latest2 ?

Comment: Have you considered using a pipe?

Comment: Can you explain how can I use pipe? It will be helpful.

Comment: @Lazarus, wouldn't that be the same as backticks, exec or system, for all practical purposes?

Comment: @Lazarus, perhaps he's actually looking to "replicate ls -ltr unix command *in perl*" [emphasis mine]

Comment: I don't think the grep needs `!/^\./`, the glob should exclude dot-files by default.

Answer (score 10):

The solutions presented here already are o.k. but probably may get slow if used on a very large directory, the sort function would then repeatedly apply -M on the same files over and over again. Therefore, one could use a  [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to avoid this (if necessary):

```
...

my @sorted_fnames =
         map  $_->[0]       ,          # ↑ extract file names
         sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }  # ↑ sort ascending after mdate 
         map  [$_, -M $_]   ,          # ↑ pre-build list for sorting 
         grep ! /^\.\.?$/   ,          # ↑ extract file names except ./..
      readdir $dirhandle;              # ↑ read directory entries

...
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: Nïce;) The *Memoize* module might also be helpful in similar situations

Answer (score 2):

`my @latest = grep { !/^\./ && -f "$_"} (sort {-M $b <=> -M $a} <$dir/*>);`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
my @latest = grep { !/^\./ && -f "$_"} (sort {-M $b <=> -M $a} <$dir/*>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl pipelined commands follow the right-to-left direction of the assignment operator. So you kind of have to think backwards. It is the operation that is done *closest* to the equals sign that it done first.

Of course, it is so second nature to me now, that I rarely think about how "backwords" it might seem. However if you grep first and then sort, you're going to have a more compressed sort, and as the best sorts are semi-quadratic, reducing the amount of items you are going to sort makes a lot of sense.

As handles are closed when they go out of scope, you can just do this:

```
my @list 
    = sort {-M $b <=> -M $a} 
      grep { !/^\./ && -f "$_"} 
      <$dir/*>
    ;
```

As you are using a [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html#DESCRIPTION) to do this, you don't need to open the directory handle. But if you were, you can do it like this:

```
my @list = sort ... grep ... 
           do { opendir( my $dh, $dir ) or die "Cannot open '$dir': $!"; 
                readdir( $dh ) 
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix `ls` has been implemented in Perl as part of the [Perl Power Tools (ls)](http://search.cpan.org/~cwest/ppt/bin/ls) suite .

Many other Unix commands are also implemented.